# Getting current user location automatically every "x" seconds and calculating the difference in km

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm trying to get the users' location every "x" seconds then calculating the difference in kilometers. Here is the code that didn't work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    <p id="demo"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">


function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


function calcCrow(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // km
  var dLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
  var dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1);
  var lat1 = toRad(lat1);
  var lat2 = toRad(lat2);

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c;
  return d;
}

async function showPosition(position) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        return "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
    var lat1 = position.coords.latitude
    var lon1 = position.coords.longitude

    console.log("Latitude "+lat1+" Longitude "+lon1);

    await sleep(1000);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        return "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
    var lat2 = position.coords.latitude
    var lon2 = position.coords.longitude
    console.log("Latitude "+lat2+" Longitude "+lon2);
    alert(calcCrow(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2).toFixed(1));
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>The element below will receive content</p>
        <div id="div" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            for (;;) {
                showPosition();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: @PolyGeo It's pure browser JS, no libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I admit that I don't quite get the logic of your code, but obviously it goes into some endless loop. You are also missing `toRad` function definition.

Here is simplified code that should work (tested):

```
function toRad(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
};    

function calcCrow(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // km
  var dLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
  var dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1);
  var lat1 = toRad(lat1);
  var lat2 = toRad(lat2);

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c;
  return d;
}

var prevPosition = null;

function showPosition(position) {
  var lat2 = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon2 = position.coords.longitude;
  
  if (prevPosition) {     
    var lat1 = prevPosition.coords.latitude;
    var lon1 = prevPosition.coords.longitude;
    var distance = calcCrow(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2).toFixed(1);
    if (distance > 0) alert('Distance: ' + distance);
  }
    
  var positionStr = "Latitude: " + lat2 + " Longitude: " + lon2;
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = positionStr;
  
  prevPosition = position;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  }, 1000);
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else {
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML =
  "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
```

Comment: When I tested it out at first it worked perfectly. But after I implemented it to [my website](https://boraofficial.github.io/Projects/Speedometer/) and Math.round'ed it (because speedometer didn't work with floats) for some reason the distance was always 0 and it didn't change. Do you know why @TomazicM ?

Comment: It seems you calculate distance in km and display it rounded to 1 decimal, which means you would have to travel distance of at least 50m in one second (which gives speed of 180 km/h) to get result other than 0.0.

Comment: That makes sense. When would you suggest me to round it?

Comment: That depends on what movement you want to measure: snails, rabbits ... Just simple math of how much your moving subject travels in one second.

Comment: I want to measure how fast my car drives using javascript. When should I round it?

Comment: That's some basic elementary school mathematics/physics calculation you'll have to figure out yourselves.

Comment: Thank you for your time @TomazicM I think I fixed it. But I need your help because I still don't know when to round it